# Team Foundation Server: Sync Source but not Project Files?

Tags: c#, tfs

I made a project in XNA 4.0 on one computer, which has VS2010 installed with TFS, while on another I have VS2012 installed and MonoGame 3.0.1 with it. Because MonoGame is essentially a continuation of XNA, code written for XNA 4.0 should work fine with MonoGame. However, the references go to different DLL files, and build slightly different. Is there a way to sync the source (.cs) and content files, but not the project and solution files in TFS?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is manually put all .CS files under source control using Team Explorer. So... don't put the project under source control, just the source files. It's very manual and you'd obviously need to manually check files in and out.

What I use are the TFS Powertools that integrate into Windows File Explorer to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you definately SHOULD synchronise the project, just don't add the files TO the project

Project 1 (xna) with no files

Project 2 (monogame) with no files

Both checked into TFS

Then add the files to a whole other root folder and check them into TFS

Then from each project, chose add existing file, and click the the split Arrow, there is an option to add a reference to the file (instead of including the file Inside the project)

That way everything (both projects and all code) are in TFS, and the code can be shared across both projects with no issues.